# What is the "submersion principle?" Showing that $SL_n(R)$ is a submanifold of $GL_n(R)$.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I'm watching the following series of video lectures on [Lie groups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygtHuxPvR0o&index=1&list=PLelIK3uylPMG3iyQ_SJYqeyjmeNC2QC3L).  In the last couple of minutes of the first lecture, he states his strategy to show that $\textrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a Lie subgroup of $\textrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$:

1 .  Show that $\textrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R}) = \textrm{det}^{-1}\{1\}$ is a submanifold of $\textrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ at $I_n$, by showing that the map on tangent spaces at $I_n$ is surjective, and then using the "submersion principle."

2 .  Use homogeneity to show that $\textrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a submanifold everywhere.

The second principle is clear to me, as well as the fact that the tangent space map at the identity is surjective.  But I don't understand what is the "submersion principle" or how it is used.  I tried googling submersion principle but nothing useful came up.  This seems to have something to do with a smooth map having constant rank in a neighborhood of a point.

Edit: Not a duplicate of the previous question of why SL is a submanifold, because I am asking about a specific approach to showing it is a submanifold.

Comment: It's a standard fact in the study of differential manifolds and differential topology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $SL(n , \mathbb{R})$ is a regular submanifold of $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952358/show-that-sln-mathbbr-is-a-regular-submanifold-of-gln-mathbbr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. By note that $SL_n(R) = det^{-1}(1)$ with $det : GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\smallsetminus\{0\}$ is a constant rank map, $SL_n(R)$ is a embedded submanifold of $GL_n(R)$. The determinant function above is a constant rank map because its a smooth map which is also a group homomorphism. By a little work we can show every smooth map between Lie group that is also group homomorphism (called **Lie group homomorphism**) has constant rank.

Comment: But where does the structure of a manifold on $\textrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ come from?  What general principle are you using to conclude that?

Comment: The structure of SL comes from the fact that its a level set of identity in $R\smallsetminus 0$. We can conclude that by [constant rank level set theorem](https://books.google.co.id/books/about/Introduction_to_Smooth_Manifolds.html?id=eqfgZtjQceYC&redir_esc=y) Th.5.12.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand why SL is a submanifold now.  What you are mentioning seems different from the approach I mentioned in my question though.  You would show first that the rank is everywhere constant using homogeneity then conclude the level set is a submanifold.  In the video lecture, he says first show it is a submanifold at the identity, then use homegeneity.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to make the approach I mentioned in my question work?  Or is it fundamentally incorrect?

Comment: Your welcome. You can look at another approach [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952358/show-that-sln-mathbbr-is-a-regular-submanifold-of-gln-mathbbr). But i think thats not the aprroach that you looking for too. I believe the proof that you look for is mentioned in the proof of Th.7.5 in Lee's Smooth Manifold. Only Lee's proof's is more general. After you read this proof i think you'll agree that what i mention is same as you meant in the beginning.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712667/show-that-sln-mathbbr-is-a-n2-1-smooth-submanifold-of-mn-mathbb